# eval as if statement condition

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, eval

Why is the output of the following statement true?

```
VAR="[[ "x"=="y" ]]"
if eval $VAR ; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Is there any other way to use a variable as condition for an if statement in bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your quoting is an issue and you need spaces around `==`:

```
VAR='[[ "x" == "y" ]]'
if eval $VAR ; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

However you must avoid using `eval` as far as possible. You can use a function here:

```
fvar() { [[ "x" == "y" ]]; }
```

Then call it as:

```
if fvar; then
    echo "true"
else
   echo "false"
fi
```

---

**Reasons** why your `eval` condition is evaluating to `true` because you have `VAR="[[ "x"=="y" ]]"` where the text inside `[[` and `]]` is being treated as a single string. Which is same as evaluating `[[ a ]]` or `[[ foo ]]`

Comment: Presumably, the real logic is a bit more complex than `"x" == "y"` because that can be evaluated to false and thereby simplify a lot of code (it becomes `echo "false"`).  But you're right that `eval` should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: This would be a better answer kif it answered the question. Why does `eval` of the string produce success? As you say, there is whitespace missing, but why is the result success? A syntax error would eval as failure... It is fine to tell people what to do, but it is better to explain why; that might save them (or someone else) fr repeating the error.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer attempt was voted down, so I'll try to clarify in hopes it at least makes it back to 0 and add something of value considering the other answer. I'll admit I was a bit unclear what you were asking.

First, are your x and y supposed to be literals or variables? Part of the reason I'm uncertain is the extra quoting in the assignment. Note these are equivalent:

```
$ VAR="[[ "x"=="y" ]]"
$ echo $VAR
[[ x==y ]]
$ VAR="[[ x==y ]]"
$ echo $VAR
[[ x==y ]]
```

So in this case, saying

```
if eval $VAR ; then
```

is the same as saying

```
if [[ x==y ]]
```

When you're having trouble with eval, you'll want to print out the value of your variable like this to see what's being executed.

The x==y is one argument, and the [[ operator on a single string argument says, "is this a non-zero length string?" For example:

```
$ if [[ dkfjek ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
true
$ if [[ any_non_zero_length_string ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
true
$ if [[ "" ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
false
```

To use the == you need whitespace. For example, without and with eval:

```
$ if [[ x == x ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
true
$ if [[ x == y ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
false
$ VAR="[[ x == x ]]"; if eval $VAR; then echo true; else echo false; fi
true
$ VAR="[[ x == y ]]"; if eval $VAR; then echo true; else echo false; fi
false
```

Usually though you really want to avoid eval unless you've really nailed down what the value of the variable can be. Consider a code snippet where you let the user decide the condition to test: you might write something like this in a script:

```
read -p "type condition> " COND; 
VAR="[[ $COND ]]"; 
if eval $VAR; 
then 
  echo true; 
else 
  echo false;
fi
```

You might run it expecting input/output like:

```
type condition> x == x
true
```

But what if someone entered this?

```
type condition> x == x ]]; touch /tmp/oh-no; [[ true
true
```

What was $VAR? What about /tmp/oh-no?

```
$ echo $VAR
[[ x == x ]]; touch /tmp/oh-no; [[ true ]]
$ ls -l /tmp/oh-no 
-rw-r--r-- 1 splante isiusers 0 Nov  3 15:17 /tmp/oh-no
```

Remember the syntax is "if <command>". The "[[" is just one possible command, but any compound command can be executed following if. Now suppose instead of `touch /tmp/oh-no` the use entered some other more destructive command? It would have executed too.

You asked "Is there any other way to use a variable as condition for an if statement in bash?" This is the typical way to compare two variables for string equivalence in bash:

```
if [[ "$x" = "$y" ]]; then ...
```

I assume now you already knew this, but I almost never use eval and just try to work the problem out differently so you don't need to have the whole condition be a variable.